# How to remove borders in primefaces datatable column of radio butto?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have written a code to generate a datatable. The datatable column contains a radio button field. All is fine with the data table, but there comes a border in the radio button field.

[image]

the code snippet is as follows:

```
<p:column id="statuscolumn" headerText="#{prop['tum.userdatatable.status']}" filterBy="#{user.activeStatus}"
        filterOptions="#{userListController.statusOptions}" sortBy="#{user.activeStatus}" style="border-style: none !important;">
            <p:selectOneRadio value="#{user.activeStatus}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Active" itemValue="true"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Inactive" itemValue="false"/>

                <p:ajax listener="#{userListController.changeStatus}"/>
                <f:attribute name="user" value="#{user}"/>
            </p:selectOneRadio>
        </p:column>
```

How to remove the borders arround the radio button field in the data table column field.
Please Help!
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: This is not the default style. It's caused by your own CSS. If you're unable to interpret CSS code, you'd better post it in the question so that we can point out the mistake.

Comment: @NDeveloper let me know how to solve